# MySQL - How to create temporary table with Python while GTID consistency is enabled?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and MySql 5.7. I'm trying to create a temporary table using the code:

```
def create_temp_table():
    cnx = connect_mysql('username', 'password', 'host', 'db')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    try:
        create_table_query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temptable (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, val1 VARCHAR(64), val2 VARCHAR(128), val3 VARCHAR(128), PRIMARY KEY (id))"
        cursor.execute(create_table_query)
        cnx.commit()
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
    except:
        cnx.close()
        raise
```

But I'm getting the error:

`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1787 (HY000): Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.`

According to MySQL manual:

"Temporary tables.  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE statements are not supported inside transactions when using GTIDs (that is, when the server was started with the --enforce-gtid-consistency option). It is possible to use these statements with GTIDs enabled, but only outside of any transaction, and only with autocommit=1."

How do I create this temporary table outside transaction with autocommit=1 in Python?